# Can't put value into map

Tags: go

I just learn golang, and want to build an struct like this.

```
{end:false map["h":{false "h" map["e":{true "e" map[]}]}
           "s":{false "s" map["h":{false "h" map["e":{true "e" map[]}]}]}
]}
```

Follow is the code I write:

```
package main

import "fmt"
type node struct {
    end      bool
    char     string
    children map[int32]node
}

func addKeyword(root *node, key string) {
    current := root
    for _, v := range key {
        mm := current.children
        if nil == mm || len(mm) == 0 {
            mm = make(map[int32]node)
            current.children = mm
        }
        child, ok := mm[v]
        if !ok {
            child = node{false, string(v), nil}
            mm[v] = child
        }
        current = &child
    }
    current.end = true
}

func main() {
    root := new(node)
    addKeyword(root, "he")
    addKeyword(root, "she")
    fmt.Println(root)
}
```

I get result is:

```
{end:false map["h":{false "h" map[]}
           "s":{false "s" map[]}
]}
```

I don't know why second level struct not append to root object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the type of `children` map. You are using `node` values in this map. As a result, you get new values every time you access a key and the changes are not reflected into the original 'parent' node.

The fault lies with this line:

```
child, ok := mm[v]
```

`child` is a *new variable* that is equal to the value of `node` `mm[v]`. The changes you make happen to this value while the `node` value in `mm` remains unchanged.

To fix this problem, you can use `*node` for values in `children`:

```
type node struct {
    end      bool
    char     string
    children map[int32]*node
}
```

And fix the code accordingly:

```
// ...
mm := current.children
if nil == mm {
    mm = make(map[int32]*node)
    current.children = mm
}
child, ok := mm[v]
if !ok {
    child = &node{false, string(v), nil}
    mm[v] = child
}
current = child
// ...
```

Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/XcmPY4Nx-O